# is the image of path metrizable?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be Hausdorff and $\alpha$ be a path in $X$.

How do I prove that $\alpha(I)$ is metrizable?

I know that $\alpha(I)$ is compact, connected, locally connected. I tried to prove this by applyin Urysohn's lemma.

Since $I$ is compact metriazble space, there exists a countable dense subset $D$ of $I$.

Fix $t_0\in I$ and $N$ be an open neighborhood of $\alpha(t_0)$. Since $D$ is dense, $\alpha^{-1}(N)\cap D \neq \emptyset$. Thus, $N\cap f(D) \neq \emptyset$. Hence, $f(D)$ is dense in $\alpha(I)$. Thus, $\alpha(I)$ is separable. However, $\alpha(I)$ need not be second countable in this case.

HOw do I prove it?

Comment: The easiest proof I know of uses the fact that the space $C(I)$ of continuous real-valued functions on $I$ (with the sup metric) is a separable metric space and the space of continuous real-valued functions on $\alpha(I)$ can be considered as a subspace of $C(I)$ via $\alpha$ and is hence also separable.

Answer (score -1):

For $x,y\in \alpha(I)$ let $d(x,y)=\inf\{\,|s-t|:\alpha(s)=x,\alpha(t)=y\,\}$.

Comment: Doesn’t work: you may have three points of $\alpha[I]$ whose fibres are $\left[0,\frac15\right]$, $\left[\frac25,\frac35\right]$, and $\left[\frac45,1\right]$. Unfortunately, $\frac35\not\le\frac15+\frac15$.